# Unable to open map with ionic 2 using variable from ts

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to open google map in ionic 2 android app.
it works fine when I use direct lat & long value. But when it come with variable from ts. It does not work.

Works Fine:

```
<a href="geo:?daddr=21.146677,79.1279979">{{ orderByInfo?.address }} - 12</a>
```

Does not open [retailerLat variable with fixed value]

```
<a href="geo:?daddr={{retailerLat}},79.1279979">{{ orderByInfo?.address }} - 12</a>
```

Comment: Could you please try with `<a [attr.href]="'geo:?daddr=' + retailerLat + ',79.1279979'">{{ orderByInfo?.address }} - 12</a>`

Comment: @sebaferreras still stuck with same. :(

Comment: The result when that is rendered is exactly the same as `<a href="geo:?daddr=21.146677,79.1279979">{{ orderByInfo?.address }} - 12</a>`?

Comment: @sebaferreras Yes in term of view everything will be same in both case. No ERROR. But with absolute number work fine means it open google map app. But when I use .ts variable it woouldn't work. I tried printing `retailerLat ` variable near address in that case as well it shows value.

Comment: Fill the `retailerLat` in `ngOnInit()` and see what happens or with fixed value on declaration.